# How to export network statistics?

Tags: export, gephi

I need to use the network statistics on a regression analysis as independent variables. How to export these statistics in variable format for use in Stata or R?

Comment: Can you do "Export table" from the Data Viewer to get all your data as CSV? This should include calculated fields such as centrality etc.

Comment: Actually, Rob, you were right! The problem was that I exported the edges list, without realizing that the network statistics were stored in the nodes list. I will leave this thread here in hopes of helping another distracted soul like myself haha.

Answer (score 3):

The statistics you calculate on the network (such as centrality etc.) will be stored on each node, along with all the usual node data.

That means you can just do `Export table` from the Data Viewer, and export all the nodes as CSV, including all the calculated network stuff.